# IBM Bluemix Liberty Java App is not displaying images

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

My ibm liberty java app is not displaying images other than the standard default image that was provided along with sample code. Is there a restriction (copyright etc.) on displaying images on ibm bluemix apps ?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no restrictions. You will have to edit the WAR file within the sample app and then push it.

Comment: Thanks! Its strange behavior. Yes i did rebuilt the war after doing my changes and adding additional images to the image folder. However the only image that i can display is the newapp-icon.png which came in with the sample. I even tried renaming other file with the name 'newapp-icon', but that too did not work.

Comment: What about the extension? Is used for mimetypes. What happens when you access it w/ a command-line client?